# Can inVals != null && inVals.Length != 0 be simplified?

Tags: c#

Consider the following code snippet.

```
class MyClass 
{ 
    public void ListInts( params int[] inVals )
    {
        if (inVals != null && inVals.Length != 0)
        for (int i = 0; i < inVals.Length; i++) // Process the array.
        {
            inVals[i] = inVals[i] * 10;
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", inVals[i]); // Display new value.
        }
    }
}
```

Is it  possible to simplify `inVals != null && inVals.Length != 0`?

Comment: Would be better in [CodeReview.SE]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you don't need to check `inVals.Length != 0` condition:

```
class MyClass { 
  public void ListInts(params int[] inVals ) {
    if (inVals == null)  
      return;

    foreach(int item in inVals)  
      Console.WriteLine("{0}", item * 10);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why so convoluted null check? Just `inVals == null` would do right?

Comment: Unlike the original code, this doesn't modify `inVals`. I think it's good that you don't modify it, I don't see the point of `params` for an array that is to be modified, but it's worth pointing out.

Comment: You wasted more keystrokes. Why didn't just use `if(inVals=null)`?

Comment: @nawfal: You're quite right, inVals == null would do here; ReferenceEquals is just my habbit: I've had a bitter experience with re-declared == operator

Comment: @Stiff Jokes: I do this to avoid arrow head antipattern. It's esier to read, IMHO, when there's no indented "if"s "for"s... It's also easier to modify: e.g. it's evedient where to throw ArgumentNullValueException if (inVals == null) is an error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    public void ListInts(params int[] inVals)
    {
        if (inVals!=null)
        {
            Array.ForEach(inVals, (x) => Console.WriteLine("{0}", 10*x));
        }
    }
```

Comment: `inVals` is initialized as `new int[0];` when no parameters are used but you can still call it with `ListInts(null);` I guess.

Comment: Yes, and since you edited it, i will remove my comment.